# Trying to disable radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, radio-button

I have two radio buttons to select priority as high or regular.

I wrote this function to disable the radiobox which was not selected. For some reason it won't disable the box though. I get no error in the consol.

```
function disablePriority(){
    var reg = $('input[value="ct100"]');
    var high = $('input[value="ct101"]');

    alert('cp');
    if(reg.attr("checked")){
    alert('cp1');
        high.attr("disabled","disabled");
    }else{
    alert('cp2');
        reg.attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
}
```

This is the html for the two radio boxes

```
<input id="ctl00_m_g_72c1058f_372a_4780_b0c6_58f4c7012b35_ff61_ctl00_ctl00" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_72c1058f_372a_4780_b0c6_58f4c7012b35$ff61$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl00">


<input id="ctl00_m_g_72c1058f_372a_4780_b0c6_58f4c7012b35_ff61_ctl00_ctl01" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_72c1058f_372a_4780_b0c6_58f4c7012b35$ff61$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl01" checked="checked">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first there is a typo in your input `value`. In the HTML it is ctl01 and ctl00 (note the small-case 'L'). In your jQuery it is ct100 and ct101.

Change the value as below, it works.

```
var reg = $('input[value="ctl00"]');
var high = $('input[value="ctl01"]');

if(reg.prop("checked")){
alert('cp1');
    high.prop("disabled",true);
}else{
alert('cp2');
    reg.prop("disabled", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `disabled` as `true` like

```
if(reg.attr("checked")){

    high.attr("disabled",true);
}else{

    reg.attr("disabled",true);
}
```

CHeck this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cHmng/)

Answer (score 0):

```
high.attr("disabled",'disabled'); or high.prop("disabled",'true');


high[0].disabled=true;high[1].disabled=true


high.removeAttr("disabled"); //to remove it
```